# android studio workmanager once a day at a specific hour

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

I'm trying to make an app that make a web request once a day and then push a notification with work manager.
Now, I managed to do everything except the part with the scheduling of the workmanager.
I want it to happen once a day at 8:00 am, but I couldn't figure out how.
Currently I'm using oneTimeWorkRequest, but I'll change it if there is a better option...
So what do you think is the best sulotion for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

// In onCreate you just call startWork(); you can change attributes in createConstraints() as you want

```
   private fun createConstraints() = Constraints.Builder()
    .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.NOT_REQUIRED)
    .setRequiresCharging(false)
    .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
    .build()


private fun createWOrkRequest() = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<NotifyWorker>(24, TimeUnit.HOURS)
    .setConstraints(createConstraints())
    .setInitialDelay(delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)

    .build()

private val delay = //TODO - here you have to calculate delay in order to start Worker at desired time. You can
```

//calculate amount of time (milliseconds) between now and 8 hours 'o clock

```
private fun startWork(){
    WorkManager.getInstance(this)
        .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
            "Some-Unique-Name",
            ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
            createWOrkRequest()
        )
}
```

Inside class NotifyWorker you call -sendNotification()

```
class NotifyWorker(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, workerParams) {

override fun doWork(): Result {
    sendNotification()
    return Result.success()
}

private fun sendNotification(){
 // Here you create notification
}
}
```

That is one way to do it, old-fashioned way is to use AlarmManagers and BroadcastReceiver()...

Comment: but if I understand the periodic workmanager correctly, this would send a notification somewhere in the 24 hour, and it is not guaranteed that it will always be at 8:00 am. maybe I can use flexIntervals, but I didn't really understand how to use them, so I don't know if it is the best thing to do...

Comment: Yes. Look at function createWorkRequest(). Here you can setInitialDelay. There you can calculate how many milliseconds is between now and next 8:00AM. Maybe it is not the best practice, but this really works for me. This will ensure that your first run of worker will be at 8 AM. It is also good to say that you can call function start work() every time you open your app. As there is ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, worker, new worker will be created only if it doesn't exist yet. If it exists, it will be kept as it was.

Comment: yes, but after the first time it's possible that the workmanager will execute at an hour that is not 8:00 am. It just to be somewhere in the next 24 hours, And I want my workmanager to be executed at the exact same hour every day...

Comment: Workmanager should do it exactly after 24 hours. Unfortunately, it might be slightly delayed. (Probably because of battery policy)

Comment: that's my problem, because after enough notifications the notifications will be pushed at 11:00 and later and later. So my question is if there is any way to keep the notifications around 8:00

Comment: Okay. This might not be the best idea, but it worked for me. You can enque unique work (one time, not the periodical) from MainActivity - setting the delay accordingly to set the time at 8 AM. Then, inside doWork() in Worker, you can sendNotification and after that enque one time work once again (with same unique name). Every time, you would have to calculate the delay -> it should be accurate every time.

Comment: I thought about it, but will it work if I will enque the same uniqe workmanager before I return success? Becuase I'm afraid that because it has the same name it won't enque the workmanager...

Comment: It works for me, I tried it. What is weird that i had to copy and paste functions startWork, createConstraints and createWOrkRequest inside worker class. When you try to call function in f.e. MainActivity, from Worker class, it threw an exception.